# Python opencv cannot load image in gray

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to change image to gray using

```
img = cv2.imread('test.JPG', 0)
```

it returns below error

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.2) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper'
```

But when I get the image with color like below, its no error.

```
img = cv2.imread('test.JPG', 3)
```

I searched online, many people said its related to image path, so I tried to use absolute path and still not working.
I also tried to get the color image first, then covert to gray, but also return same error.

```
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: Try `img = cv2.imread('test.JPG', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`.  I have had a similar issue before.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739144/11365539

Comment: @fmw42 yes, and still same error

Comment: What is your version of Python and what is your version of OpenCV. Did you import cv2?

Comment: @fmw42 Python v2.7, opencv v3.4.2, and yes I already import cv2. When I change back `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` to 3, can load the image right away.

Comment: @Warpstar22 the example is using npy file and I only have jpg file, can I still do like this? If you mean need to change the data type to 'uint8', it already is 'uint8' when get the image as color.

Comment: Perhaps you need to upgrade Python to 3.x? Maybe you have too old a version of Python and it is not compatible. Or your install was not correct for OpenCV for that version of Python.